# Tuples Pattern Matching list Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a function where I have a list of 2-tuples and it returns the tuples that correspond to True. The first character is a String and the second character is a Boolean. This is what I want:

```
pack  [ ("a", True), ("b", False), ("c", False), ("d", True) ]
       returns [ ("a", True), ("d", True)  ]
```

Here is my code:

```
pack :: [String] -> [Bool] -> [(String, Bool)]
pack [] [] = []
pack (x:xs) [] = []
pack [] (y:ys) = []
pack (x:xs) (True:ys) = (x, True) : pack xs ys
pack (x:xs) (False:ys) = pack xs ys
```

I can only get { returns [("a", True), ("d", True)] } only by typing in

```
pack ["a", "b", "c", "d"] [True, False, False, True]
```

and this is not what I want and am confused how to approach this. Any help, guidance, or link would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `pack = filter snd`

Comment: @4castle I would love to use that, but I am trying to do this without using any built in Haskell functions

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use the description of what you are trying to implement to show you what my steps towards a solution would be. Hopefully that helps you converge on your own solutions in the future.

If I rephrase it, you want a function with the following signature:

`pack :: [(String, Bool)] -> [(String, Bool)]`

That is, you have a list of 2-tuples (the first element being a `String`, the second element being a `Bool`) and you want to end up with a list of the same type.

You want to *filter* all the tuples of this list and only keep the ones with a `True` value. The prelude happens to have a function just for that:

`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

The first argument of `filter`, a function `a -> Bool` called a *predicate*, lets you define what you want to keep in the second argument (the first `[a]`).

Note that `a` can be any type at all, so we could replace `a` with `(String, Bool)` and `filter` would have the following type:

`filter :: ((String, Bool) -> Bool) -> [(String, Bool)] -> [(String, Bool)]`

It's starting to look closer and closer to our target signature for `pack`! What we are missing is the predicate `(String, Bool) -> Bool` that will tell `filter` what we want to keep:

```
isTrue :: (String, Bool) -> Bool
isTrue (_, True)  = True
isTrue (_, False) = False
```

Finally, we can implement `pack` in term of `filter` and `isTrue`:

```
pack :: [(String, Bool)] -> [(String, Bool)]
pack = filter onlyTrue
```

You've mentioned in a comment that you do not want to use any "built-in" function. Let's get rid of `filter` then, and write `pack` closer to the original style you've posted:

```
pack [] = []
pack (x:xs)
    | isTrue x  = x : pack xs
    | otherwise = pack xs
```